# When first TextView is too long, second disapper

Tags: android, textview

I have two TextView's. When the first one is too long the second one disappear. I have tried RelativeLayout with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, but it doesn't realy work for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
        android:text="@string/movie_title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
        android:text="@string/new_sounds"
        android:textColor="#8C1717"
        android:textSize="13sp" 
    android:visibility="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's going to be a layout for single row in ListView, where first TextView is movie title and sometimes there will be another Text visible. But, like I said, when movie title is long `textView2` is invisible on the screen. What should I do to have it where the first one ends (for example it ends in second line, and then next to it is going to be `textView2`)

Comment: Change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to match_parent (both textViews), and add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" to textView1. This should do the trick. Write if it works.

Comment: Not really. All in all I made LinearLayout with `android:layout_weight`. It's not what I wanted, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, which would make the text view to go as long as the text inside it. You could change it to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or a specific width, then it would be limited to whatever is specified.

Comment: @divoom12 I noticed after posting. I hadn't refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/movie_title"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/new_sounds"
    android:textColor="#8C1717"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set `android:layout_weight="1"` to each textview, then they can share the